# SSTORE to stockpile gas for times of high prices?

Tags: gas, evm

lets assume Gas drops to 5 GWei. I could have a contract, which performs a bunch of SSTORE operations. 20k Gas each
Now, assume Gas increases to 50 GWei. Now I will empty the storage slots SSTORE[x] = 0 and get a refund of 15k Gas.

Results: I have savings on my gas costs for other operations. According to the Yellow Paper there is a 50% of transaction costs being payed by refunds.

Am I missing something?

Comment: the best opcode to save gas is the MOVE opcode. MOVE to Arbitrum, or MOVE to Polygon

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [gas token](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/fundamentals-of-gas-tokens). Multiple such tokens existed in the past.

Because of the harmful nature of gas tokens and filling up the block space, [Ethereum op-code pricing was changed in London hard fork](https://blog.1inch.io/ethereums-london-hard-fork-will-make-some-tokens-useless/) so that gas tokens are no longer practical.

Comment: But I could still deploy such functionality within a contract for myself?

Comment: If you think you can, just go ahead.